# Impedance of hands-free speaker

Tags: power, impedance, speakers

How much is impedance of a typical hands-free speaker and how much power is needed to properly drive it?

[image: A typical hands-free speaker]

Comment: A typical one these days is BlueTooth.

Comment: By typical hands-free i mean hand-frees with 3.5 mm jack

Comment: A common impedance is 32 ohms, but there's no real standard for it.  Power is typically measured in tens of milliwatts, but again, that can be design- and application-specific.

Comment: If you have a specific one in your possession that you want to use, you can just measure the (approximate) impedance with an ohmmeter and then calculate the power by measuring AC voltage while it's running.  Watts = Volts^2 / Ohms

Answer (score 1):

Lightweight headphones and earbuds usually have a nominal impedance of 32Ω.  A few tens of milliwatts should be enough to drive them properly.  Once you get into hundreds of milliwatts, the sound levels can become dangerous.

The efficiency of headphones and speakers varies considerably, so you'd need the specifications to work out how many milliwatts you'd need for a given volume level.

See also [What wattage should a headphone amp be?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36469/what-wattage-should-a-headphone-amp-be)